# How To Amend This SOQL to get All records for today After 6am

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, soql, salesforce-service-cloud

Is there a way I can customize this SOQL query to include all records after 6am from Today?

```
SELECT Case__c, Level_1__c, Level_2__c,Level_3__c 
   FROM Case_Type__c  
   WHERE createddate = today 
   GROUP BY Case__c,Level_1__c, Level_2__c,Level_3__c
```

I need to do this within the SOQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HOUR_IN_DAY()` from [date functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)

Something like:

`WHERE CreatedDate = today AND HOUR_IN_DAY(CreatedDate) > 5`